# Container with corners divs

Tags: html, css

I want to make a layout where the container div has 4 children divs which are expanding from corners of the container div. Each div expands from one corner. I want to achieve this without setting position absolute to the childreen because this messes  with my other css. This is where it stopped: 
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcKYF/2/

```
<div class=container>
<div class=div1>11</div>
<div class=div2>22</div>
<div class=div3>33</div>
<div class=div4>44</div>
</div>

.container
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:red;
}
.div1
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:green;
}
.div2
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:yellow;
}
.div3
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:blue;
}
.div4{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:violet;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by expanding?

Comment: Depending on content. The start from the corner and expand into the center.

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you mean without an illustration/example but I think what you are asking for is very difficult without `position: absolute`

Comment: If you're using position: absolute, you need to use position: relative on the container, which will stop the absolutely positioned elements from affecting the rest of the page flow

Comment: Why on earth would this mess up your other css? Usually that just means, you're not able to adress the consequences.

Comment: Basically you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Meu/) without positioning the container absolutely, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/94U4U/1/

I think what you are looking for is a relatively positioned container that takes up the page, which is divided up into 4 corners plus a central content holder:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
.container
{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.container div.corner{
  height:20%;
  width:20%;
  position:absolute;
}

.container div.content{
  background-color:white;
  height:60%;
  width:60%;
  position:absolute;
  left:20%;
  top: 20%;
}

.div1
{
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:green;
}

.div2
{
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#FF0;
}

.div3
{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:blue;
}

.div4
{
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#EE82EE;
}
```

Comment: I've got it. I've just set my container to relative position and children to absolute positioning.

Comment: @fox I've also refactored your code a bit, there was some repetition in the CSS. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XcKYF/6/

Not sure if that completely solwes your problem, but that is how something similar to what you want could be done.

HTML:

```
<div class=container>
    <div class=div1>11</div>
    <div class=div2>22</div>
    <div class=div3>33</div>
    <div class=div4>44</div>
    some other content<br/>
        some other content<br/>
        some other content<br/>
        some other content<br/>
        some other content<br/>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
}
.div1
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
}

.div2
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.div3
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.div4
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:violet;
}​
```